# Undefined offset: 1 in http://mysite_url/../Java.inc on line 1067

Tags: php, php-java-bridge

I have two scenarios: one for development (windows) and another for production (unix)

Development env in Windows:
I have a apache web server which calls an apache tomcat server that has installed a javabridge in order to call a jasper report. (Everything is on localhost) and everything works fine.

Production env in CentOs:
I have an apache web server that calls another tomcat server (that has java installed) by javabridge in order to call a jasper report. (Here is where I get the error)

In tomcat server I can execute Javabridge functions and examples but when I call them from apache web server it fails

I am getting this error

```
 Undefined offset: 1 in http://mysite_url/../Java.inc on line 1067 Fatal error: unknown error: please see back end log for details in http://mysite_url/Java.inc on line 869
```

When I try to execute this code:

```
<?php

    //Parametro en caso de que el reporte no este parametrizado
    $Parametro = new java('java.util.HashMap');
    ?>
```

The exact code in tomcat server Java.inc file is (line 1067)

```
function parseHeaders() {
$this->headers=array();
$line=trim(fgets($this->socket,JAVA_RECV_SIZE));
$ar=explode (" ",$line);
$code=((int)$ar[1]);  // LINE NUMBER 1067
if ($code !=200) $this->headers["http_error"]=$code;
while (($str=trim(fgets($this->socket,JAVA_RECV_SIZE)))) {
if($str[0]=='X') {
if(!strncasecmp("X_JAVABRIDGE_REDIRECT",$str,21)) {
$this->headers["redirect"]=trim(substr($str,22));
} else if(!strncasecmp("X_JAVABRIDGE_CONTEXT",$str,20)) {
$this->headers["context"]=trim(substr($str,21));
}
```

And the other line in Java.inc is (867):

```
function dieWithBrokenConnection($msg) {
unset($this->protocol->client->protocol);
trigger_error ($msg?$msg:"unknown error: please see back end log for details",E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

**UPDATE**
When I call the link from development env this is the generated header:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" [1]=> string(3) "200" [2]=> string(2) "OK" }
```

When I call it from production env the header is empty

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

What could be the problem? Is there any option in the server that take out the header of a response or something like that?

Comment: Per SO policies, please include code in the question itself instead of linking to it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what does the log say ?

Comment: Log isnt showing me anything. I updated the question.

Comment: So, are you certain that `$ar` contains at least two elements? Because the undefined offset is telling me that `$ar` is either empty or has only one element (remember that arrays are zero-indexed!)

Comment: The next line is  ----> $Parametro->put("id", $id); but this line is never executed. I can tell you this because I have a print after java.uti.hashmap and never is executed

Comment: @RodolVelasco Before line 1067 in your Java.inc, please add this line and share its output: `var_dump($ar);`

Comment: var_dump($ar) showed me array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Everyything is working fine but I dont know why when I execute the link from development environment the header is sent OK (same url but different host) but when I executed from production environment the header is not well formed

Comment: @ChrisForrence what could be generating the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the Javabridge is functioning correctly in production?

Comment: 1. When I run http://my_url/JavaBridge/ ... every example runs ok.  2. When I run the report from my computer to tomcat server (production) it seems that everything is ok. It has to be some configuration on tomcats server that is taking out the header or something like that.

Comment: It seems that you have some connection problems, check that you have all ports open and listeners ready to serve.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem (Y). I provided an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was ok, the problem was that I was trying to access the other server by public ip so the firewall was somehow taking out the header of the request.

The solution was to change the public ip to same network local ip and everthing started to work and java.inc started to read the header of the request so every place in Java.inc and JavaProxy.php you have to set network ip and tomcats filesystem variables too.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for my bad english
I have same problem..
I solved this problem by inactive tomcat port  (8080) on kaspersky internet security. 
Go to setting -> additional -> network.
Chose **select** on radiobutton **monitor selected only**.
inactive port 8080.
its OK and running well on win 10.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!!